# HTML table is not appearing as it should in outlook email

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to create a HTML table for the input csv file I receive using shell script.
Once the script for HTML table is generated using shell, I send it to outlook email.
Generated html file appear as intended in chrome/edge browser

But the problem is,  same HTML table get distorted in email(like cell contents break into next cell, contents of cell breaks into 2 lines etc...)

I'm new to HTML and don't know what's wrong with the HTML table I'm creating.
please help with correct format of this table, so it don't get distorted when shared via mail.

Sample HTML table generated:

```
<html><head><style>
table, tr, td {font-family : Tahoma, sans-serif; border: 1px solid; border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 12px; width: 100%; white-space: nowrap;}
.green {background-color: #98FB98; color: black}
.red {background-color: #F08088; color: black}
.grey {background-color: #C0C0C0; color: black}
.white {background-color: #FFFFF; color: black}
</style></head>
<body><table>
<tr bgcolor="#87CEFA";>
<td><b>Employee_Id</b></td>
<td><b>Name</b></td>
<td><b>Experience</b></td>
<td><b>Address</b></td>
<td><b>Phone</b></td>
<td><b>Detailed Report</b></td>
<td><b>Report timestamp</b></td>
<td><b>Report Status</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class=white>6666</td>
<td class=white>Gowri</td>
<td class=white>3 years</td>
<td class=white>K R Pet, Mandya.</td>
<td class=white>5562462962</td>
<td class=white>The report has been shared with manager</td>
<td class=white>2023-01-25 22:24:32.0</td>
<td class=green>Success</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class=white>7777</td>
<td class=white>siva</td>
<td class=white>4 years</td>
<td class=white>Shivamogga</td>
<td class=white>3562462962</td>
<td class=white>The report has been shared with manager</td>
<td class=white>2023-01-23 22:24:32.0</td>
<td class=red>Failure</td>
</tr>
</table></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is html tries to fit the content in table according to width it gets so when the text becomes so lengthy it simply overflows so you can **limit the characters** to be displayed in the particular cell using javascript string functions.this is how the actual outlook does you see limited characters and when you click on the cell you see whole characters to be displayed

Comment: Is the table format correct,  is there any change required

Comment: yes i is correct